# Background image no more visible in the preview

Tags: customization

Since this morning, background image of my website project is no more visible in the build-up page & preview.
If I publish my page, the view is OK but as I am using white color for my text, it makes it impossible for me to develop my pages.

Note that I am using Elementor (but the issue also occurs in the Gutenberg preview) and the issue occurred after installing the latest Elementor update...

Comment: You should contact Elementor support. Questions about third-party plugins like Elementor are off-topic in this Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.